# Excel VBA - Text from TextBox in the active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to build a simple UserForm with a TextBox and a CommandButton, which opens itself by clicking inside a **empty cell** in a special column (for example in the column A, the cell A1) inside the worksheet. When I enter a text and hit the button, the entered text should be pasted in the active cell (A1).

The building of the UserForm is not the problem, but the actions which are behind it.

Do you guys have an idea how to solve this? Or even better pieces of code?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look at events of worksheets and controls, so the Click event of a button, then you'll need to use the text or value of the combobox.   A little gooogling will explain a lot about this. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a piece of code that will run when you click a cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
            'name of userform .Show
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Where the code has a comment you need the name oof your userform and then `.Show`

Entering the text into, lets say A1 as you suggested, would be:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

TextValue = TextBox1.Text

[A1].Value = TextValue

End Sub
```

Change the `CommandButton1` and `TextBox1` to whatever you named them(if you named them, which you should)

If you need anything clarified just ask

Comment: Thanks for your help! Do you have an idea, how to open the UserForm in the whole column of A? 
`If Selection.Count = 1 Then
        Dim check As Boolean
        check = True
        If check Then
        Dim i As Long
            For i = 1 To 100000
                If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A" & i)) Is Nothing Then
                    UserForm1.Show
                    check = False
                End If
            Next
        End If
    End If` This was my idea, but it is very slow, when you have to go trough 100000 cells.

Comment: Another question is, if there is another way of adding the text to the cell, because If I click in one cell in the whole column, I don't know, where I am going to click. I tried to save the target in a public variable, but that doesn's work.

Comment: Those would need to be new questions, comments arent big enough to put in the answers for those, if my answer has resolved your initial question then please accept this as an answer

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The new question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36060525/vba-open-a-userform-by-clicking-anywhere-in-a-specific-column).