# VBA - Open a UserForm by clicking anywhere in a specific column

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to build a makro in VBA which opens a UserForm when I click in a cell in a specific column, for more details look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031611/excel-vba-text-from-textbox-in-the-active-cell).

With this code (from [Mr.Burns](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5784703/mr-burns)):

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
       If Selection.Count = 1 Then
           If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then
            'name of userform .Show
           End If
       End If
   End Sub
```

I was able to open the UserForm by clicking in the cell A1, but not by clicking in any cell inside the column A.

I tried to solve this problem with this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  If Selection.Count = 1 Then
    Dim check As Boolean
    check = True
    If check Then
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 100000
            If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A" & i)) Is Nothing Then
                UserForm1.Show
                check = False
            End If
        Next
    End If
  End If
End Sub
```

It actually works fine, but it is very slow, is there any better possibility to solve this?

Comment: I see what you wanted now `If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1")) Is Nothing Then` change the `A1` part to the colun you want and the number you want, so `A100000` for instance, that will activate the userform within those cells

Comment: But I would use florentbr answer as it covers the whole of column A, so if you add more rows in there wont be any future problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the form when a cell is selected in column A:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  ' if target is one cell and in column A
  If Target.Columns.count = 1 And Target.Rows.count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then
    UserForm1.Show
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.count` and `.column` property together with `AND` and it will become so much simple and fast. Following code triggers pop-up if u click in column A on active-sheet

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
On Error GoTo errorhandler
If Target.Count = 1 And Target.Column = 1 Then '.count to check if only one cell is selected and .column to check if it is a first column
    'UserForm1.Show
    'Do whatever you want to do here like opening User form
    MsgBox "You clicked in column A"
End If
errorhandler:
End Sub
```

Comment: I wouldn't use Target.Count, it produces an overflow error when all the cells are selected.

Comment: @florentbr "Clicking" is the process which is meant to trigger the macro, and selecting all cells using mouse is highly unlikely, but to avoid error its better to put `on error goto` statement before `if` statement